# A specific spanning property of a family of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $v_1, v_2, v_3, \dots$ be a family of vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ that span $\mathbb R^n$. Given this family, define the family of vectors
\begin{align*}
  \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ \alpha_1 v_1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} v_2 \\ \alpha_2 v_2 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} v_3 \\ \alpha_3 v_3 \end{pmatrix}, \dots
\end{align*}
in $\mathbb R^{2n}$. My question is under which conditions on $v_1, v_2, v_3, \dots$ and the $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3, \dots$ the family of vectors in $\mathbb R^{2n}$ is spanning. Partial solutions are also welcome.

Comment: At the risk of pointing out the obvious, I'll note that a necessary condition is that the family have at least $2n$ members.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to know more about what kind of results you're looking for, or the motivation, to better answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say there are $N$ indices $i$.  Let $V$ be the $n \times N$ matrix whose columns are the $v_i$ and $A$ the $N \times N$ diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $\alpha_i$.  Then what you're asking for is that the $2n \times N$ block matrix
$$ \pmatrix{V\cr VA}$$ has rank $2n$.  As Gerry commented, we need $N \ge 2n$.  This is equivalent to there being a 
set of $2n$ indices  such that the corresponding $2n \times 2n$ matrix $\pmatrix{W\cr W B}$ is nonsingular, where $W$ is the $n \times 2n$ submatrix of $V$ corresponding to those $2n$ columns, and $B$ the $2n \times 2n$ submatrix of $A$ corresponding to those $2n$ rows and columns.

For example, in the case $n=2$, $N=4$,  the condition can be written as
$$ \eqalign{&\left( v_{{1,3}}v_{{2,4}}-v_{{1,4}}v_{{2,3}} \right)  \left( v_{{1,1}
}v_{{2,2}}-v_{{1,2}}v_{{2,1}} \right) \alpha_{{1}}\alpha_{{2}}\cr -&
 \left( v_{{1,2}}v_{{2,4}}-v_{{1,4}}v_{{2,2}} \right)  \left( v_{{1,1}
}v_{{2,3}}-v_{{1,3}}v_{{2,1}} \right) \alpha_{{1}}\alpha_{{3}}\cr+&
 \left( v_{{1,2}}v_{{2,3}}-v_{{1,3}}v_{{2,2}} \right)  \left( v_{{1,1}
}v_{{2,4}}-v_{{1,4}}v_{{2,1}} \right) \alpha_{{1}}\alpha_{{4}}\cr+&
 \left( v_{{1,2}}v_{{2,3}}-v_{{1,3}}v_{{2,2}} \right)  \left( v_{{1,1}
}v_{{2,4}}-v_{{1,4}}v_{{2,1}} \right) \alpha_{{2}}\alpha_{{3}}\cr-&
 \left( v_{{1,2}}v_{{2,4}}-v_{{1,4}}v_{{2,2}} \right)  \left( v_{{1,1}
}v_{{2,3}}-v_{{1,3}}v_{{2,1}} \right) \alpha_{{2}}\alpha_{{4}}\cr+&
 \left( v_{{1,3}}v_{{2,4}}-v_{{1,4}}v_{{2,3}} \right)  \left( v_{{1,1}
}v_{{2,2}}-v_{{1,2}}v_{{2,1}} \right) \alpha_{{3}}\alpha_{{4}}
\ne& 0}$$

Answer (score 1):

As has been noted the number $N$ of vectors needs to be at least $2n$. Also the list $V=(v_1,\ldots,v_N)$ needs to contain a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$, otherwise the matrix $V$ has rank less than $n$ and thus 
$$ \begin{pmatrix} V \\ VA \end{pmatrix}$$
has rank less than $2n$. Without loss of generality we may assume that the first $n$ of the list are linearly independent. Let's partition $V= (V_1,V_2)$ accordingly and do the same for the diagonal matrix. We are then looking at
$$ \begin{pmatrix} V \\ VA \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} V_1 & V_2 \\ V_1A_1 & V_2 A_2 \end{pmatrix}.$$
As $V_1$ is invertible we may eliminate the block $V_2$ without changing the rank. I.e. 
$$ \begin{pmatrix} V_1 & V_2 \\ V_1A_1 & V_2 A_2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} I_n & -V_1^{-1}V_2 \\ 0 & I_{N-m} \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} V_1 & 0 \\ V_1A_1 & V_2 A_2 - V_1 A_1 V_1^{-1}V_2\end{pmatrix}.$$
The question is thus whether $V_2 A_2 - V_1 A_1 V_1^{-1}V_2$ has full rank, or equivalently whether 
$$ V_1^{-1}V_2 A_2 -  A_1 V_1^{-1}V_2 $$
has full rank. This looks like a [Sylvester equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation) in $X=V_1^{-1}V_2$. So for instance, if $V_2$ is also $n$-dimensional and the diagonal elements of $A_1$ and $A_2$ are distinct, you can take any invertible matrix $C$ and there exists a unique $X$ such that
$$ X A_2 - A_1 X = C.$$
Then choose any invertible $V_1$ and let $V_2 = V_1 X$.

Comment: oh this is great! I will read through it in detail soon. Do you have an idea how one can generalize this to higher-dimensional cases, i.e. $\begin{pmatrix} V \\ VA \\ VB \end{pmatrix}$ where $B$ is some other diagonal matrix?

Comment: @Fiego24: Well, now we need at least $3n$ vectors. In principle, what I have done is called taking the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement). The Schur complement in the first display is the expression $V_2 A_2 - V_1 A_1V_1^{-1}V_2$. This you can do indefinitely, i.e., first make the $V,VA$ block full rank, permute so that the first $2n$ vectors are linearly independent, then take the next Schur complement etc. It is just that the formulas do not get prettier and the nice reduction to a Sylvester like equation seems to go away. At least I cannot see it offhand.